# ASP.NET Core 3.1 issue with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI 3.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core, asp.net-identity

My .net core 3.1 web app was running properly on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Until I scaffolded Identity by Microsoft v1.0.

When I execute `sudo dotnet run` inside the project folder, all working as expected.

But.. when I execute this through my service, I'm getting the following error.

```
Dec 14 19:07:12 app systemd[1]: Started Web.App.
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]: Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui/3.1.10/staticwebassets/V4/
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsFileProvider..ctor(String pathPrefix, String contentRoot)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.<>c.<UseStaticWebAssetsCore>b__2_0(ContentRootMapping cr)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at System.Linq.Enumerable.OfTypeIterator[TResult](IEnumerable source)+MoveNext()
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssetsCore(IWebHostEnvironment environment, Stream manifest)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.<>c.<ConfigureWebDefaults>b__9_0(WebHostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder cb)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<ConfigureAppConfiguration>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
Dec 14 19:07:13 app web-app.service[9268]:    at app.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in /var/www/app/Program.cs:line 13
Dec 14 19:07:13 app systemd[1]: web-app.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Dec 14 19:07:13 app systemd[1]: web-app.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Dec 14 19:07:19 app systemd[1]: Stopped Web.App.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who experienced the same issue, here's my core version:

```
.NET Core SDK:
 Version:   3.1.404

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.404/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.10
  Commit:  1721e39439

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.404 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

---

**I've tried the following:**

1. I've installed all packages related to Razor runtime - didn't helped.
2. I've installed all packages related to AspNetCore Identity - didn't helped.
3. Re-created the service - didn't worked.
4. Clean, rebuild, delete all, clean fetch from git etc.. - nothing worked.
5. All ubuntu packages are up to date. 0 updates. just in case.. - didn't helped.

---

**My problem was at the service ExecStart path.. (publish folder)**

The original ExecStart,

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/app/web-app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/web-app.dll
```

After I've added the publish folder, it worked as expected.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/app/web-app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish/web-app.Web.dll
```

---

The thing is that I have identical server with exactly the same versions of everything. I scaffolded Identity exactly the same way, its currently running perfectly without the publish folder.

Interesting thing is that I run dotnet successfully from within the folder, but when I run it from the service it complains about it.

Comment: Is your code working with Identity and login on Ubuntu 20.04LTS ? Didn't manage o make my application. Work with Identity on .Net 5... It works perfectly without but with identity it crashes. Plus it works perfectly on Windows server ... I was willing to go full open source but I wasted to much time on fixing issues.

Comment: Yes, the code is working with Identity and login on Ubuntu 20.04LTS. I'm still with .NET Core 3.1 didn't migrated to 5 yet.

Comment: Thanks for you answer I think I'll try A clean reinstall off everything with the .NET core 3.1 .NET 5 seems still a bit buggy on Linux tbh

Comment: Quick heads up, if you'll have any issues with the rendering of identity scaffolded pages, it has something to do with Razor runtime compilation so simply set services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

Comment: Thanks I'll try this fix and see if it's working